# Make " an active quote while including subfiles with spaces in their path

Tags: csquotes, subfiles

I'm preparing a book. There is a requirement that the individual sections are available as separate files, so I'm using the `subfile` package. I would really like to keep the ability to name my TeX files after the section titles, which include spaces and accents, and that all works with XeLaTeX. MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\subfile{"á é/ő ű.tex"} % file contents are irrelevant to problem

\end{document}
```

However if I add to the preamble

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
```

I get an error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\begingroup
l.10 \subfile{"á é/ő ű.tex"}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
```

Is it possible to use this active quote and include subfiles with spaces in the path and have these two features not break each other? I suspect the easy solution would be if the `\subfile` macro could use something else as the delimiter.

Comment: I'm not saying that is impossible - perhaps some tricks with \detokenize work - but why are you making the compilation so fragile? It can cost you many hours to handle problems with accents, funny chars and spaces.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer long story. Consider it a project requirement. Or we can discuss in chat

Comment: How about `\DisableQuotes` and `\EnableQuotes` around your `\subfile` calls? Btw, this question is a nice example for https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472729/105447.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at `csquotes` docs, section "10.5 Active Quotes in Special Contexts". `babel` and `underscore` might help you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple: you can use `'` as the delimiter too. So you can do this and it works:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\begin{document}

\subfile{'á é/ő ű.tex'}

\end{document}
```